# What are the branches of Graphic Design

Tags: website-design, print-design, designers

Does anyone know what is the full-branch of Graphic Design and the title for the person doing it.

```
Graphic Design
|- Web Design - Web Designer
|- Illustration - Illustrator
|- Photo Manipulation - Photo Manipulator
```

...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no official taxonomy for the various species of designers.

UPDATE:

If you want to take a go at creating your own, some various titles that you might see in the graphic design world:

- advertisement specialist
- advertising designer
- animator
- art director
- book setter
- brand manager
- broadcast designer
- cartoonist
- compositing artist
- copywriter
- creative director
- data visualization specialist
- director
- environmental designer
- exhibition designer
- exhibition fabricator
- graphic artist
- graphic designer
- illustrator
- instructor / teacher
- instructional designer
- interaction designer
- interactive designer
- interface designer
- logo designer
- marketing manager
- motion designer
- multimedia designer
- multimedia specialist
- package designer
- photo editor
- photographer
- prepress operator
- presentation designer
- producer
- production artist
- publisher
- senior designer
- sign maker
- sign painter
- signage and way finding designer
- technical illustrator
- type designer
- typesetter
- UX designer
- video designer
- visual artist
- visual communications specialist
- visual designer
- web designer
- web developer

The catch is that none of those are necessarily isolated skill sets. Throughout a career, a designer will often be wearing a variety of those hats, often several at the same time.

On top of that, there's no real rules at to what a title implies in terms of seniority or salary from one company to the next. It's mostly arbitrary.

Comment: But If I can gather some large list of taxonomy then maybe someday we can make it official. :)

Comment: I updated my answer with a list to get you started. Good luck! ;)

Comment: Wow, Thanks for updating the list. I would try to add more if I can discover new ones.

Comment: I added a few more. Only one that was already on there I'm not sure about is exhibition fabricator. I think generally that would fall into a fabrication/construction role.

Comment: I sorted the document so duplicate entries won't be edited.

Comment: ermm.. barista, therapist, ad rep, customer service, IT specialist -- Perhaps merely new since 2012 `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Following are the major fields of Graphic designing:

Multimedia Designer

Web Designer

Logo Designer

Brand Identity Designer

Flash Designer

Creative/Art Director

Photo Editing/Photoshop Artist

Layout Artist

Comment: Flash designer? I'm sorry, but afaik, Flash has died a silent death not too recently :). Thanks for your answer, though, and welcome to GDSE, Abigail! If you have any questions, have a look at the [help] and feel free to pop into our chat room [chat] once your reputation allows you to!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there's already an older answer with a longer list including what you mention here. Check [answer] to learn more about the site.